# How does Access/VBA handle division by null?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am working on converting a legacy application from MS Access/VBA to C#.  To put it mildly, there are some issues with the quality of the legacy code.  There is at least one spot in the VBA code that results in a potential division by null (as well as a potential division by zero, but I can handle that).

How does Access/VBA handle division by null?  In most programming languages, anything divided by null will result in null, but VBA isn't "most programming languages".  My assumption is that a division by null should result in null, but I want to be sure.  I am trying to mimic the behavior of the original application as closely as possible, so I need to know what the behavior of this operation would be in Access/VBA.

Comment: Access VBA Primer on Nulls:http://allenbrowne.com/casu-11.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm late to the party here, but just to give you something definitive...

According to Microsoft's VBA specification ([MS-VBAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd361851.aspx)) [section 5.6.9.3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177477.aspx):

•For binary arithmetic operators, unless otherwise specified, the effective value type is determined as follows, based on the value types of the operands:

```
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
|            Left Operand Value Type             |            Right Operand Value Type            | Effective Value Type |
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Null                                           | Any numeric type, String, Date, Empty, or Null | Null                 |
|------------------------------------------------|------------------------------------------------|----------------------|
| Any numeric type, String, Date, Empty, or Null | Null                                           | Null                 |
+------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

(Note that "binary" in this case is in reference to the fact that these operators take two operands, as distinct from "unary" which take one)

Comment: Thanks for providing a link to the VBA spec from Microsoft and confirming my suspicion.

Answer (score 3):

Null is a funny value. VBA compiler will throw error when you are trying to assign the Null value to a Data Type "Invalid use of Null", commonly tacked by the usage of Nz() function or a brief If Else structure. However any arithmetic operation performed on a Null value will result in Null.

```
? 75 + Null
Null

? 56 * Null
Null

? 6.3 / Null
Null

? True = Null
Null
```

So given this scenario, yes the answer is Null !